# Kill already in use binding tcp connection

Tags: http, ubuntu, tcp, kill, ps

Kill already in use binding tcp connection

I ran a web application with the following log:

```
2015/01/05 12:57:56 Listening http://0.0.0.0:80
2015/01/05 12:57:56 listen tcp :80: bind: address already in use
```

It was not working because I already ran this before I ran the script.

Is there anyway that I can force to unbind or kill the process that binds this port
so that I can rerun the script and serve the same port with different code?

I am using ubuntu and want to kill the binding tcp using `ps` or `kill` command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use netstat to figure out which process is listening
2. Kill the corresponding process

Assuming root permission:

```
kill $(sudo netstat -tlpn | 
       perl -ne 'my @a = split /[ \/]+/; print "$a[6]\n" if m/:80 /gio')
```